# RoboVM facebook binding invitable_friends issue (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, robovm

I have upgraded my robovm-1.0.0-beta-04, libgdx-1.5.4 game to latest [robovm facebook binding](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/facebook/src/org/robovm/bindings/facebook)

I am getting below error :

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

when I try to get invitable facebook friends by using following code snippet :

```
private void getUninstalledFriends() {
    logger.d("Getting friends!!!");
    facebookManager.request(getNotInstalledFriends(new FacebookRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GraphObject result) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookError error) {
            ...
        }
    }));
}

public static FacebookRequest getNotInstalledFriends(FacebookRequestListener listener) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("fields", "name,picture.width(128).height(128)");

    return new FacebookRequest("me/invitable_friends", parameters, HttpMethod.GET, false, listener);
}
```

It was working with pretty old version of facebook binding. Is there anyone who can get invitable friends using latest robovm facebook binding?